# How do I pass a version information to MSBuild within Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am doing a build in the cloud via VSTS.  In this case I am publishing a click-once application and providing MSBuild arguments:

```
/target:publish
/property:PublishUrl=http://somurl.com/somepath/myapp.application
/property:ApplicationVersion="1.$(Year:yyyy).0.0"
```

I really want that last one to be:

```
/property:ApplicationVersion="1.$(Year:yyyy).$(DayOfYear).$(Build.BuildNumber)"
```

However, anything but a hard-coded string gives me:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3506,5): Error MSB3174: Invalid value for 'AssemblyVersion'.

If I use a hard-coded version number (e.g, "1.0.9.99") it works fine.

Comment: i guess $(Build.BuildNumber) causes it to fail. See the documentation: Note: This value can contain whitespace or other invalid label characters. In these cases, the label format will fail.

Comment: If you look at the logs, you should see the variables replaced with their actual values on the MSBuild command line, that might give you a hint as to what's gone wrong.

Comment: As DaveShaw said, seeing what is actually being generated would be very helpful, but if I had to wager a guess I think $(Build.BuildNumber) is now $(Rev:.r)

Comment: I can look into use $(Rev:.r), however, it fails with "1.$(Year:yyyy).0.0" so the problem is not only $(Build.BuildNumber).  Looking at the command line I see exactly what I provided on the last run with /property:ApplicationVersion="1.$(Year:yyyy).9.99" followed by /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_69032c25-257b-4e1c-9d04-ab3ecdea470a_build_44_1427" which I did not provide.

Comment: @KirkLiemohn - it looks like `$(Year:yyyy)` isn't a valid [variable](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables) to me - I cannot see it on that page, where did you get that from. It isn't valid powershell either AFAICT.

Comment: @DaveShaw, I found it here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/general.  This seems like it should be reasonable to use.  Maybe I'm in the wrong context to use it?

Comment: Yes, I think those are just tokens for the build name, and are not variables available through out the entire scope. You might be able to use a Powershell task to initialise some variables with the current year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all who commented on my question.  It helped me come with a solution which I'll provide here in case it helps others.

Apparently the tokens defined [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/general) can be used when setting up the build number format and then used in build tasks arguments by passing in $(Build.BuildNumber).  Some other tokens can maybe be used as task arguments such as $(Rev:r), but others such as $(Year:yyyy) and $(DayOfYear) cannot be used as task arguments (although they can be used to set the build number format).

I never tried just passing in $(Rev:r) as I chose to change my build number format to be a valid assembly version number (it wasn't previously). I changed it to:

```
1.$(Date:yyyy).$(Date:MMdd).$(Rev:r)
```

Now I pass that as an argument into a gulp script and use that gulp script to call msbuild.  A little convoluted as I could have called msbuild directly, but I'm using gulp for other things and it has other configuration that I would have otherwise had to hard-code into arguments for the msbuild task so I chose to keep it in gulp.

Using gulp to call msbuild, however, required that I know the path to msbuild.  Testing an msbuild task showed me what the full path was, so I could add that to my configuration for the environment (see [npm config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) if you are interested in learning more about that).

Answer (score 2):

First you should make sure that the build number format you have set in the build definition options is in an accepted format like W.X.Y.Z.

Next, you can pass the build number in your msbuild arguments:

```html
/property:ApplicationVersion="$(Build.BuildNumber)"
```

Make sure you add the variable name between a double quotes, otherwise you will keep getting the same error message you are getting.

Comment: Best answer. Works like a charm, thanks