# Invalid value for 'AssemblyVersion' when building valid csproj

Tags: c#, msbuild, azure-devops

I have a project which references a few other projects. They are all built using x86 as the platform. This compiles just fine on my desktop.

During my remote VSO build I am always getting the error

> MSB3174: Invalid value for 'AssemblyVersion'

When I edit the `.csproj` file, I see nothing wrong with it. What am I doing wrong?

VSO build arguments are simply:
/t:Publish /p:ApplicationVersion=$(Build.BuildNumber)

I have other projects that use $(Build.BuildNumber) with no problems

Arguments as seen on VSO build log (snipped for clarity):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe" "[App_PATH].csproj" 
/nologo 
/nr:false 
/t:"Clean" 
/dl:CentralLogger,[*snip dll path] 
/t:Publish 
/p:ApplicationVersion=DEPLOY.[App_Name]_2016.11.09.16 
/p:platform="x86" 
/p:configuration="DV1" 
/p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS[*snip]"
```

EDIT: I tried running the MSBuild from a local command prompt and I get the same behavior. VSTS or any of its setup info is not to blame.

I just wish I knew were to look in my app to correct it.

Comment: Do you have an steps the populate the AssemblyVersion (usually in AssembliyInfo.cs) as part of your build - maybe using a variable that isn't present or is different on the build server?

Comment: Could you show us the part that you think there's nothing wrong with? Do you override this with command line parameters like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40223153/how-do-i-pass-a-version-information-to-msbuild-within-visual-studio-team-service)?

Comment: There is a step before the build to update the AssemblyFileVersion in the AssemblyInfo.cs file however I a- verified that it is doing its job correctly and b- I've run the build without it and I get the same behavior. The default values for AssemblyVersion:1.0.0.0 and AssemblyFileVersion:1.0.0.0

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue with a new project? You can share the project on the OneDrive.

Comment: The [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228177.aspx) for this error are quite good.  Use the /v:diag option to jack up the build trace details so you can see this going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
/p:ApplicationVersion=DEPLOY.[App_Name]_2016.11.09.16
```

The version format does not meet the requirement. Please try with this format: 1.2.3.4.

Refer to [MSBuild Error MSB3174](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228177.aspx) and [Version Constructor (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0hf9t2e.aspx) for details.

> **Remarks**
>
> The version parameter can contain only the components major, minor,
>   build, and revision, in that order, and all separated by periods.
>   There must be at least two components, and at most four. The first two
>   components are assumed to be major and minor. The value of unspecified
>   components is undefined. The format of the version number is as
>   follows. Optional components are shown in square brackets ('[' and
>   ']'): major.minor[.build[.revision]] All defined components must be
>   integers greater than or equal to 0. For example, if the major number
>   is 6, the minor number is 2, the build number is 1, and the revision
>   number is 3, then version should be "6.2.1.3".

Comment: It turns out that the Build Number Format in the generals tab was incorrect. I used this value to correct the build: $(Date:yyyy.MM.dd)$(Rev:.r)